# Show entire table view inside cell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, cell

I need to display a dynamic table view inside a cell (of a static table). Using sections instead will not be enough for me. But I don't want this table to be scrollable, so the entire table must appear at once. The problem is that this table size [and rows count, and each row size] varies according to the content being shown. How can I associate the cell (which holds the table) autoresizing property with a table inside that must show all content at once?

Currently I have the tableView inside the cell, and constraints bonds it to all the 4 sides. The first table (not the one inside the cell) rowHeight property is set to UITableViewAutomaticDimension, but the table inside the cell doesn't appear entirely.
If I set the static cell height to a value greater than the tableView(inside cell) height, the whole table appears, and also an extra space beneath it (as the table is bounded to 4 sides of the cell)

So, any ideas on how to show this entire table inside a cell that dynamically has the perfect size for it ?

ps: I tried using collection view inside the cell. Unfortunately it doesn't serve my purpose.

Thanks!

**Update**

I tried to create a class for the inner table and use (as pointed by [iamirzhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6749063/iamirzhan)) contentSize didSet, like so:

```
override var contentSize:CGSize {
        didSet {
            self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }
```

I then used this method to call a function that resizes the cell that holds the table: `self.frame.size.height = table.contentSize.height`. The function is on this cell's own class.
This worked, the table now appears entirely. The problem is that it overlaps the cell underneath it, so i'm still looking for a solution.

Comment: Can you somehow provide the design you are trying to achieve? Perhaps TableView inside tableView is overkill...

Comment: cells of inner tabel are static in height ???

Comment: the height of the inner table cells may vary as well

Comment: Dominik Bucher, I'm trying to achieve a table view with 6 static cells, with different content on each one (picture a blog post: text, than an image, than more text, than a list of itens etc). The inner table i'm mentioning in my question would be equivalent to the list of itens. (Its not a blog app, but the example fits)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why this requires 2 tableviews.  The static portion should be uitableviewheaderfooters or just a UIStackView.  But to answer your question simply query your child tableView for its size and return this in [tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview?language=objc) for the outer tableview.  The height of the child tableView is simply the sum of the hieght of all of its children (including any headers/footers).  This is usually not difficult to calculate unless you are using something like a webview where you need to actually load the content and get the size asynchronously.  You can calculate the size of elements that are based on their intrinsic content size with [UIView.sizeThatFits(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622625-sizethatfits).  The other elements should have fixed sizes or constants in the storyboard that you can sum up.

Comment: But how do I calculate the child table height while inside `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` ? The child table won't have loaded yet, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

For inner tableView you should write such implementation.

Firstly, disable the scrollEnable flag

Then you should override the intrinsicContentSize method of tableView

Your inner tableView custom class:

```
class IntrinsicTableView: UITableView {

   override var contentSize:CGSize {
        didSet {
            self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }

   override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        return self.contentSize
    }
}
```

Now, delete the height constraint, and the height will be calculating by its content.

Comment: Still, the cell doesn't resize to fit the table. 
Should I also be using heightForRowAt, or tableView.rowHeight on the main table?

Comment: Yeah, you should set the estimatedRowHeight and the rowHeight=UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. The height does change but not enough. I then added a class to the cell holding the tableView and added a height constraint to the inner table, then I created a function to change the height when contentSize didSet is called. Once again, the height changed but not enough. 

Then I tried to use `self.frame.size.height = innerTable.contentSize.height` on the cell class. This is called when the innerTable contentSize is set. 
This worked. The table is now shown entirely. However, it overlaps the cell underneath.